# Dex file in Android does it matter it's exported or not?

Tags: android, jar, dex

I have an Android project and it depends on one jar file. In order for the app to run, I need to export the jar to APK. The jar will be dexed and classes in the jar will be packaged up into the apk.

Now I want to move this jar to framework: meaning modifying framework.jar and put my classes in it:

I move framework.jar back to Android device. 
When I compile my Android app, I don't need to export my .jars anymore.

My question is: Will those files still be dexed and account for number of dexed methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These classes will not be included in your app .dex file and will not count against the number of dexed methods. However, they will be dexed and count against the limit for the framework.jar.

**Edit:** As [@JesusFreke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531021/jesusfreke) mention in a comment, methods in framework.jar you invoke *will* be counted against the .dex method limit. However, an app rarely uses all classes and methods in a framework, so there will still be substantial savings.

Comment: do you know how can I check dexed method count?

Comment: This isn't quite true. Any methods that the apk directly references/calls will count against the method limit in that dex file, even if the definition of the referenced method is external to the dex file.

Comment: @JesusFreke, do you imply only the calls that the apk reference will count? Eg: if my jar has 100 methods and the apk only calls 10, only 10 will count?

Comment: @JesusFreke, I saw from android forum:  http://tinyurl.com/cbpvtyz#10 jessewil...@google.com
"I'm curious, how did you arrive at 56,484 for the number of methods? The 65,535 limit includes both the methods from your own application, plus all the platform methods that your application invokes.
"

Comment: @Lily, The number is a count of all distinct methods that are either defined or referenced by your apk. So yes, if you only call 10 from the external jar file, only those 10 would count.